# PHP FetchAll() Not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, syntax

I was wondering if somebody could help shed some light as to why this PHP code is not entering into the for loop? In MySQL the query returns the appropriate rows that I need but in this PHP file it fails to return anything into the array, thus not executing the `foreach` loop.

**CODE**

```
<?php

  try {
  $sql = 'SELECT FirstName,LastName ';
  $sql .= 'FROM adventureworks.employeedepartmenthistory ';
  $sql .= 'JOIN employee USING(EmployeeID) ';
  $sql .= 'JOIN contact USING(ContactID) ';
  $sql .= 'WHERE DepartmentID = 2';
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo $sql;
  echo '<ul>';

     foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $emps){
     echo "<li>" . $emps["FirstName"] . $emps["LastName"] . "</li>";
  }

  echo '</ul>';

  $stmt = null;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error";
  echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

I even have the program echo the SQL query and I copy that into MySQL and it still works. Could it be a simple syntax error or is it the table joins that im performing?

Also im certain that the program is contacting the database correctly because I have other similar PHP files working properly like this one:

```
<?php

try {
  $sql  = 'SELECT department.Name FROM adventureworks.department';
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();

  echo '<ul>';

  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $depts) {
     echo "<li>" . $depts["Name"]  . "     ->  ("  .
     "<a href='deptEmps.php?deptID=" . $depts['deptID']
     . "'>Employees </a>)" . "</li>\n";
  }

  echo '</ul>';

  $stmt = null;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error";
  echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: ...and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php then edit your post to contain the errors, if any.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, although PHP does not recognize this as an error. It is simply running a query and not receiving rows in return. I dont believe error handling will pinpoint this

Comment: @AbraCadaver That ^ I believe was meant for you ;-)

Comment: @DaveDiienno *"I dont believe error handling will pinpoint this"* - You think? I see no error handling/checking here. You're coding blindly and figuring everything's OK.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors if you don't turn on error reporting? errors != exceptions

Comment: I have a file that reports any database connection errors which is what $dbh is. Im having a problem with $emps not being populated. I will dig deeper into what you both suggested and see if anything shows up

Comment: And the same query ran through MySQL workbench is returning the appropriate data, that is why I am troubled to see my PHP script not fetching the same data as it did in my working PHP scripts in my OP

Comment: Just try:  foreach ($stmt->fetch() as $depts) { ...

Comment: I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the PHP script was that I was not specifying which tables to select from. This was harder than it should have been since the syntax above returned data in MySQL which was the database I was accessing, The correct PHP script that is working can be found below:

**Working PHP:**

```
<?php

try {
$sql = 'SELECT contact.FirstName,contact.LastName ';
$sql .= 'FROM adventureworks.employeedepartmenthistory ';
$sql .= 'JOIN adventureworks.employee USING(EmployeeID) ';
$sql .= 'JOIN adventureworks.contact USING(ContactID) ';
$sql .= 'WHERE DepartmentID = 2';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
echo $sql;
echo '<ul>';

 foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $emps){
 echo "<li>" . $emps["FirstName"] . $emps["LastName"] . "</li>";
}

echo '</ul>';

$stmt = null;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Error";
echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

I was wrong that the tables would have been assumed through the `JOIN` in PHP as they are in MySQL.